# What happens to people whose bodies are not buried after death?

Tags: death, grave

I want to ask that people who are not buried after death like if they died at sea or burnt but not buried, how they are answerable to munkar nakir and how they would go through their phases of grave?

Comment: Oops, it looks an interesting question which I didn't think about that. But as a rule, their souls or spirits will go to a specified  place, in order to be present to answer the questions of Nakir-Munkar ... / God Bless You for asking such interesting and even significant query.

Comment: JazakAllah for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salam. Yeah it is a good question. Since you have asked it, I am pondering and searching about its answer. I could not get much references from Quran and Hadith but there is one Hadith in Sahih Bukhari as:

> Bukhari :: Book 9 :: Volume 93 :: Hadith 597
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   Allah's Apostle said, "A man who never did any good deed, said that if he died, his family should burn him and throw half the ashes of his burnt body in the earth and the other half in the sea, for by Allah, if Allah should get hold of him, He would inflict such punishment on him as He would not inflict on anybody among the people. But Allah ordered the sea to collect what was in it (of his ashes) and similarly ordered the earth to collect what was in it (of his ashes). Then Allah said (to the recreated man ), 'Why did you do so?' The man replied, 'For being afraid of You, and You know it (very well).' So Allah forgave him."

Here the situation is a bit same but it would not happen for all humans the same. In that situation, the islamic scholars have agreed that if a person dies and is not engraved, His spirit or rooh will be tortured if he were a bad man and will be furnished with joy if he were a good man. Along his spirit his body will also be treated accordingly where ever it is.

> The dead are to be questioned whether they are in their graves, or in any place; in the desert, the sea, or in the belly of a beast of prey. In all cases they will be questioned; their spirits will be questioned. They will be questioned and tortured if they are evildoers, and they will live in comfort and ease if they are pious. Their spirits will enjoy Paradise or suffer Hell. The remaining part of their body will go either to Paradise or to Hell in the way that Allah (Glorified and Exalted be He) Alone wills, but the spirit will suffer largely the torments in Barzakh (period between death and the Resurrection) whereas both the body and the spirit will suffer torment and pain or will feel happy and enjoy Paradise on the Day of Judgment.

More over, Allah knows the best as He is going to give comfort or punishment to the dead. Could I help you or do you have some more to ask?

Comment: `...and will be furnished with joy if he were a bad man`: You sure you don't mean "a good man" here? Also, your second quote is missing a citation.

Comment: @goldPseudo Yeah I corrected that. And the second quoute is from a fatwa site so I didn't think about it as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Qabar is name where body parts are found. It does not only mean a dig. So immidiately same procedure is applied.

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. While your answer may be correct, it could use some textual evidence.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and many still have. You can read Surah Abasa(no.80) Quran 80:21 which says "Then He causes his death and provides a grave for him". Now we need a mind to ponder here it could be/not be what we think like a physical place on earth. Also not only grave, there are people eaten by animals and some other reasons can also be there for death. Also in Surah Saffat it is there "He would have tarried in its belly till the day when they are raised"; (37:144).
Now all it needs a clear mind to think and reflect. Also please keep in mind that always answer cannot be exactly like what we expect or think. Allah knows best what does it mean. We can try our best to understand.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

As far as punishment for soul those who body is burnt seems to have some validity but what about questioning in grave and all the fear that mullah puts in your heart about grave. that does not seem to apply to those whose body is never buried in grave.
Please only reply with sahi hadith with reference or from quran with reference do not just say what your little head think and understand

Answer (score -4):

Hi there is no grave punishment.. only soul punishment..thanks
Times stops when you die..after death everthing happens in another dimension..Allah will put you straight away in to heaven or hell not in grave

Comment: This answer could profit from some evidences to support your claims (see [answer]).